# Mobile Twitter always redirects to home in Android WebView

Tags: android, twitter, webview

I have an embedded WebView in an Android app opening a simple twitter page.

Twitter would infinitely load until I added:

```
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Now it loads but redirects to twitter home even though the webview reports the correct URL.

Here is the code:

```
webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        
webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(activity));
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webview.loadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/some_account");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has recently changed the way it handles various user agents. We should find out what exactly they are expecting and doing but I don't have the time. To fix this issue, change the user agent of your WebView like this:

```
WebSettings webSettings = yourWebView.getSettings();
String opera10 = "Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X; U; en) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.10";
webSettings.setUserAgentString(opera10);
yourWebView.loadUrl(...);
```

The Opera user agent and Twitter mobile site work as expected.

Alternatively, you can remove the Android in the user agent string but that leaves the WebView rendering without properly resizing to fit the screen.